# HTML5 videos not playing in chrome with https

Tags: node.js, html, sails.js, html5-video

Here is my code to stream videos (I use Sails.js)

```
// ./api/controllers/AttachmentController.js
module.exports = {
  stream: (req, res) => {
    "use strict";

    let attachmentId = req.params.id;

    Attachment.findOne(parseInt(attachmentId))
    .then( file => {

      let stat = fs.statSync(file.path);
      let total = stat.size;

      if (req.headers['range']) {
        let range        = req.headers.range;
        let parts        = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
        let partialstart = parts[0];
        let partialend   = parts[1];
        let start        = parseInt(partialstart, 10);
        let end          = partialend ? parseInt(partialend, 10) : total-1;
        let chunksize    = (end-start)+1;

        let stream = fs.createReadStream(file.path, {start: start, end: end});
        res.writeHead(206, { 'Content-Range': 'bytes ' + start + '-' + end + '/' + total, 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'Content-Length': chunksize, 'Content-Type': file.mimetype });
        stream.pipe(res);
      } else {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Length': total, 'Content-Type': file.mimetype });
        fs.createReadStream(file.path).pipe(res);
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      sails.log.error(err);
      return res.serverError();
    })
  }
}
```

In the view

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <video class="embed-responsive-item center-block" controls="controls">
    <source src="/attachment/stream/332" type="video/mp4" />{{ __('Video not supported') }}
  </video>
</div>
```

When I access to my video with http it works on all browsers. When it's https, it works on all browsers but Chrome.

- node.js : v5.11.1
- sails.js : v0.11.4
- chrome : v51.0.2704.106 m

---

**EDIT :** When looking for Chrome version, it updated itself to 52.0.2743.82m and now it works.